# Mysql and onbeforeunload

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, onbeforeunload

Hi I'm trying to delete a row in a mysql database when the user leaves a page on my website but it's not working for some reason. I know the onbeforeunload works because if i delete everything in there and just put alert("test"); the alert shows. Can this not be done? My code is below thank you for any help

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
    var id = document.reset.id.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "Resetter.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {'id':id},
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?PHP
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db("Colleges");
    $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Table` WHERE `ID`='" . $id . "'");
    mysql_close();
    die();
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: If `$id` is numeric, you should not be enclosing its value in single quotes. MySQL will not complain about it in standard mode, but it's not correct. You're also entirely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks; what if I accessed your script with `?id=' OR 'true`. Every row in the table would be deleted.

Comment: @GFlam, Have you find solution? as i am new to php so kindly express batter and easy way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're closing the page you're closing the connection to the server and therefore it won't wait for you Ajax call to finish. This isn't how `onbeforeunload` works. It's client-side only. Also note, that `onbeforeunload` can be a little finicky in my experience and doesn't account for every way a user can move away from your page.

To accomplish what you want, you'd have to set up some sort of **[long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)**. Here's an example using PHP on the server-side: http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/

You could also use something like [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) to listen for connections and disconnections from the page.

Comment: makes a lot of sense thank you for the answer and suggestion on how i can accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

You are not `echo`ing anything from your `PHP` hence the alert in your `$.ajax` callback function is not shown... :)

Try

```
<?PHP
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db("Colleges");
    $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Table` WHERE `ID`='" . $id . "'");
    mysql_close();
    if($delete) {
        echo "Done";
    } else {
        echo "Not Done";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Would he get an alert even if there was a response body? He's already navigated away from the page before the callback can occur. The problem he wants to fix is the row not being deleted, not failing to see an alert message.

Comment: oh! I guess, that is why the `ajax` call is not working. Page unloads before the request is made... My bad... :(

Comment: thanks for the answer but i knew that wasn't the case cause in the die call i had some text in it before i pasted and i also knew because the row wasn't deleted :)